# SSRS url parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2016

In SSRS I want to set parameter value of `First Name` through `url`, Default value is `All`.

So If I want to set `First Name` : `Joanna`, My url will be :

```
http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/foldername/reportname&rs:Command=Render&parametername=[TableName].[ColumnName].&[Joanna]
```

It is giving following error

> The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other
>   restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path
>   must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath) Get Online Help

But however if I need to set value `All`, My url changes to below which is working fine. :

```
http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/foldername/reportname&rs:Command=Render&parametername=[TableName].[ColumnName].[All]
```

Just by adding `&` its showing me error.

Is there any other way to set parameter value ?